# Access target property (not type) when mapping with AutoMapper + Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm in the quite interesting situation where I require my AutoMapper to be able to map objects from type `TSource` to `TDestination` with the following constraints:

1. During mapping, I need access to a service provided by `IServiceProvider` (or, to be more precise, from the dependency injector).
2. My mapping function needs to know what the mapped property is on the destination object. This means I don't need to know that the target property is of type `string`, but that the property is called `Name` or `Address` on the mapped type. The reason for this is that I need to be able to access attributes of this property.

The first constraint can be solved <strike>rather easily</strike> unconveniently by using a custom value resolver or value converter.

```
public class MyValueResolver<TSource, TDestination> 
    : IValueResolver<TSource, TDestination, string>
{
    private readonly ISomeService _someService;

    public MyValueResolver(ISomeService someService)
    {
        _someService = someService;
    }

    public string Resolve(TSource source, TDestination destination, 
        string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        string result;

        // Perform some complex logic with _someService and attributes of
        // the target property...

        return result;
    }
}
```

But I cannot figure out how to know which property the resolver is mapping on the destination object. Is there a way to retrieve this information within the `Resolve(source, dest, member, context)` method?

*We are using the most recent version of AutoMapper in ASP.NET Core.*

Comment: `IMemberConfigurationExpression.DestinationMember`

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I found this one before, but as far as I can see there is no way for me to inject it into the value resolver, right?

Comment: I don't know what your DI container can do, but that's the value you need to pass. Hopefully it's obvious how you can do that without DI.

Comment: Well, there is no way to pass additional arguments to the value resolver. You can only create a new or resolve an existing instance and pass it to the `MapFrom(...)` method. But creating a new instance would require me to have access to the DI in my mapping profile, which I don't have and which is exactly the reason I want to use value resolvers or converters.

Comment: How would you inject the target property if AM wasn't involved at all? I think a better approach is to use ForAllMap/ForAllPropertyMaps and consider the attributes when configuring the resolvers for your members.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu In the end, accessing the property proposed by you has been part of the solution. So, thank you for pointing it out to me!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem by using a custom `IValueConverter` rather than a `IValueResolver`. The converter allows me to pass some data during mapping, where it is also possible to pass new objects with multiple contents:

```
public class MyValueConverter<TSource> : IValueConverter<KeyValuePair<TSource, MemberInfo>, string>
{
    private readonly ISomeService _someService;

    public MyValueConverter(ISomeService someService)
    {
        _someService = someService;
    }

    public string Convert(KeyValuePair<TSource, MemberInfo> data, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var source = data.Key;
        var targetProperty = data.Value;

        string result;

        // Perform some complex logic with _someService and attributes of
        // the target property...

        return result;
    }
}
```

For simplicity I've chosen to pass a simple `KeyValuePair` in my example in favour of a custom object, but both works. The Method can be called with:

```
CreateMap<MyEntity, MyEntityViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Action, opts => 
        opts.ConvertUsing<MyValueConverter<TEntity>, KeyValuePair<TEntity, MemberInfo>>(src => 
            KeyValuePair.Create(src, opts.DestinationMember)));
```

Comment: Well, that's interesting :) I don't think I saw this one before. But I take it it works. The intent here was for you to pass a member on the source object, but I guess you can pass anything.